# Error Page - how to print stack trace in JSP

Tags: spring, exception

I've created exception handling in my Spring application using spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. Everything works fine. Now I need to somehow print the caught exception within the jsp page. Something like message and stack trace. In my jsp I've found the exception object in "exception" attribute. All I need to do is something like that:

```
${exception.printStackTrace()}
```

But I don't know how. Is there any way how to do that?:-)

Thanks for any suggestion,

Mateo

Comment: You can't find the API for the name of the method? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(). Questions should always list what kind of error you're getting. Even if it is, that line doesn't output anything

Comment: @Juan I believe @mateo meant he can't find a way to printStackTrace() into the page content, which is difficult to replicate exactly without inline code (eew) to set up a PrintWriter around a StringWriter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of is to loop over the stack trace elements, taking advantage of the `Throwable.getStackTrace()` method:

```
<c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="element">
    <c:out value="${element}" />
</c:forEach>
```

You'd need to add some formatting, of course.

Comment: +1. But one shouldn't really print stacktraces in a JSP. Users love stacktraces ;)

Comment: @Bozho: Aye. I assume this is for diagnostic purposes, but for that I'd just use Tomcat's default error page. Hey ho.

Comment: Yes I use it exactly for diagnostic purposes, I don't have access to the Tomcat log and I've customized this page yet. So I thought that this would be easier than to use Tomcat default error page again:-) But anyway, thanks...

Comment: @Bozho, having a stacktrace printed in a custom built page on a dev, test and local environments is great. In our project we have maven profiles for each deployment environment so we set a property that will provide a boolean parameter if you want the stacktrace shown or not. For prod is false, for everything else is true. This gives developers easy way of getting to the exception - they don't have to go through the log files... Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Had to do this (dev/local environment only) in pages in the past and just want to display it in a textarea or a preformatted block. The output from skaffman prints out each strack trace element but not the message and exception class.

If you want it pre-formatted as per a printStackTrace() consider using Spring EL and commons-lang3.

```
<spring:eval expression="T(org.apache.commons.lang3.exception.ExceptionUtils).getStackTrace(exception)"/>
```

Comment: Another advantage of this printing as per printStackTrace is it outputs stack for the cause as well