# When using Spring, how do I print a stack trace in in my error 500 page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, error-handling

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/support/500.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

**500.jsp**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ page import="org.slf4j.Logger" %>
<%@ page import="org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" %>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scout/support/style.css"/>
<title>Scout 403 Error page</title>
</head>
<body>
      //how do I get a stack trace to print out?
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Page - how to print stack trace in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442400/error-page-how-to-print-stack-trace-in-jsp)

Comment: no I'm not using this C out crap as listed                            <c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="element">
    <c:out value="${element}">
</c:forEach>

Comment: I beg your pardon? At any rate, you can replace `<c:out value="${element}">` with just `${element}`.

Comment: I'm obviously unskilled in this area. Please do demonstrate

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, since it includes spring in the picture

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't print stacktraces to the user. He doesn't care and will be scared of the "ugly error".

Instead log the exceptions. This should be automatically done by spring, but you can make your own implementation of `HandlerExceptionResolver` to do that.

Comment: When someone asks "How do I do X?", it is actually not very useful to answer simply "Don't do X".  Only a totally braindead developer would ever show a stack trace to the user.  Clearly, the OP wanted this for development.  Please treat questioners with a modicum of respect.  And if he does display a stacktrace to users, he'll hear from them soon enough.

Comment: Often stating the obvious is useful. And I did answer the question, didn't I ;) I never treat a question with anything. It's always "viable for getting answer"

Comment: You specifically did *not* answer the question of how to print the stack trace when using Spring.  You said "don't print it."  Why stop there?  Let's go the next step and say "Don't use Spring, there's better frameworks."  Let's keep going and say "Don't use Java, there's better languages!"