# How to print stack trace in Spring MVC Error handler

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver in my application

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
   <property name="exceptionMappings">
      <map>
         <entry key="Exception" value="error.htm"/>
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error.htm" />
</bean>
```

My Error Handler is also simple

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("error.htm")
public class ErrorController {


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getErrorReport(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp"); 
        }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getErrorPostReport(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        TreeMap<String,Object> map=new TreeMap<String,Object>();
        map.put("isDataChange", true);
        map.put("isBigError", true);
        return new ModelAndView(JSONView.RenderObject(map, response));
        }

}
```

How can print Exception message and Exception stack trace (or email it) in my Error Controller?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Thanks for the reply. I want to print stack trace in jsp as well as in console. I also want access to object in ErrorController itself so that I can use that information to email logs (since some of the calls are ajax based, (they use POST), error.jsp will not be useful there so I need some way to access that information in controller itself).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442400/error-page-how-to-print-stack-trace-in-jsp does this help?

Comment: Do you want to print the stacktrace on your jsp or to your console/logfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `getErrorReport` method does nothing except returning jsp page, you can return it in the bean declaration:

```
<property name="defaultErrorView" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp" />
```

And in the page you have access to the `exception` model object:

```
<c:forEach items="${exception.stackTrace}" var="element">
    <c:out value="${element}">
</c:forEach>
```

As mentioned in the comment.